# How to resolve Promise?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I develop application with react native and I gave warning in console `backend.js:32 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):` when I get an error.

I have 2 components. Here is code snippet from the parent component **Sms-Registration.js**

```
signInWithPhoneNumber = (phone) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return (
          // this function authenticate user in firebase
          auth()
            .signInWithPhoneNumber(phone)
            .then((confirmResult) => {
              this.setState({
                formSubmitted: false,
              });
              this.getSignInResult(confirmResult, phone);
              return resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              throw error;
            })
        );
      });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <PhoneNumber
            signInWithPhoneNumber={this.signInWithPhoneNumber}
          />
    );
  }
```

here is **PhoneNumber.js** code snippet

```
signInWithPhoneNumber = () => {
    this.props
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(
        `${this.state.countryObj.dial_code}${this.state.phoneNumber}`,
      )
      .then((result) => console.log('new result', result))
      .catch((error) => console.log('new error', error));
  };
```

Can someone help me to resolve this Promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the rejection, this means that you have to call reject() inside your catch block in the same way you call resolve if everything goes well